# React JS how to get script inside dangerouslySetInnerHTML executed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-tag-manager

How to get script inside ***dangerouslySetInnerHTML*** get executed?

```
class Page extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <script
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: `
          console.log('hello world');
          window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
          window.dataLayer.push({
            event: 'viewCart'
          });
        ` }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

I can't get `console.log('hello world')` executed. Anybody can help? Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React: Script tag not working when inserted using dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35614809/react-script-tag-not-working-when-inserted-using-dangerouslysetinnerhtml)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't because script tags are removed automatically for security.

The best way to work with javascript is to get the string separately and execute (or eval) it from *componentWillMount* or *componentDidMount*

```
class Page extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    const jsCode = `
      console.log('hello world');
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      window.dataLayer.push({
        event: 'viewCart'
      })
    `;
    new Function(jsCode)();
  }

  // you can do something else here
  render() {
    return (
      <noscript />
    );
  }
}
```

You can obviously use any string. I presume you might be loading it from the server.

In the example above I used `new Function()()` which is very similar to `eval()` but works faster.

I used `componentDidMount` so i'm certain the script executes after the view is shown. Another difference between Will and Did mount is that Will mount executes on both server and client sides of universal (isomorphic) apps, whereas Did mount will only execute on the client side of universal apps.

Comment: It's Will mount that is executed on both, not Did mount

Comment: @MichaelRasoahaingo thanks for catching this. Fixed.

Comment: Would love a reference link to the react docs where the script tag is removed. I see that the script is written, but seems to be completely ignored.

Comment: It's not the React issue, it's how innerHTML should works
This is because script tags injected via innerHTML are not executed for security reasons:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

Comment: @pherris see answer below

Answer (score 9):

Script elements don't get executed because of the way that `react-dom` creates them.

When `ReactDOM.createElement` receives a type of `'script'` it uses `.innerHTML` instead of using `document.createElement` like you might expect.

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = '<script></script>';

var element = div.removeChild(div.firstChild);
```

Creating the script in this way sets the "parser-inserted" flag on that element to true. This flag tells the browser that it should not execute.

---

https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/c2a2d8a539bf02e40c43d36adc2826e228f30955/packages/react-dom/src/client/ReactDOMComponent.js#L406

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML#Security_considerations

https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html#innerhtml0