# Making <script> tags work with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using dangerouslySetInnerHTML to show posts fetched via WP REST API on react site. However, posts that embed contents via script tags are not being able to do that. For example, I can't show gists on the site. What are some workaround for this?

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37803559/react-js-how-to-get-script-inside-dangerouslysetinnerhtml-executed

Comment: (Finding those did not take more than typing “dangerouslySetInnerHTML execute script code” into Google … so next time try proper research yourself first please.)