# content in <script> tag to ReactJS component

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs, indexeddb

Here is my code in HTML, in this I need to take out the script part and modify it to ReactJS and use as script source in html again. Since, I started it as html itself and new to React.

```
<script>
  function idbOK() {
      return "indexedDB" in window;  //check whether indexeddb is supported in the browser
  }
  var db;
  var key = 100;
  $(document).ready(function() {
      if(!idbOK()) return; 
      var DBopenRequest = indexedDB.open("ora_idb3",1); 
      DBopenRequest.onupgradeneeded = function(e) {  
          var thisDB = e.target.result;
          console.log("running onupgradeneeded"); 

          if(!thisDB.objectStoreNames.contains("notes")) {  
              var notesOS = thisDB.createObjectStore("notes", {autoIncrement: true}) 
              console.log("makng a new object store notes");
              notesOS.createIndex("title","title",{unique: false});
          }
      }

      DBopenRequest.onsuccess = function(e) {  
          console.log("running onsuccess");
          db = e.target.result;
          getNote();
          $('#note').on('input propertychange change', function(){
            addNote();
         })

      }

      DBopenRequest.onerror = function(e) { 
          console.log("onerror!");
          console.dir(e);
      }

  });
</script>
```

I want to change the code to ReactJS. Am new to ReactJS and found this complex to move.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do so by the following approach:

```
const dbSetupScript = `function idbOK() {
  return "indexedDB" in window;  //check whether indexeddb is supported in the browser
}
var db;
var key = 100;
$(document).ready(function() {
  if(!idbOK()) return; 
  var DBopenRequest = indexedDB.open("ora_idb3",1); 
  DBopenRequest.onupgradeneeded = function(e) {  
      var thisDB = e.target.result;
      console.log("running onupgradeneeded"); 

      if(!thisDB.objectStoreNames.contains("notes")) {  
          var notesOS = thisDB.createObjectStore("notes", {autoIncrement: true}) 
          console.log("makng a new object store notes");
          notesOS.createIndex("title","title",{unique: false});
      }
  }

  DBopenRequest.onsuccess = function(e) {  
      console.log("running onsuccess");
      db = e.target.result;
      getNote();
      $('#note').on('input propertychange change', function(){
        addNote();
     })
  }

  DBopenRequest.onerror = function(e) { 
      console.log("onerror!");
      console.dir(e);
  }
});`;
```

Note: If you want some variable value then, can use `${variable_name}` syntax inside `dbSetupScript` string.

Then from React component's render method you can do the following

`<script dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: dbSetupScript}} />`

Comment: The script tag will be added to the DOM but it will not be evaluated... https://stackoverflow.com/a/53510757/3498950