# How to use script tags in a Gatsby blog post

Tags: javascript, markdown, gatsby

I've just started moving my blog to Gatsby but have run in to a problem.

I have many markdown pages where I have javascript demos and I need to include the javascripts using <script src="..."> tags.

These don't seem to work which I'm guessing is because of the way Gatsby renders things.

Any ideas how I could make this work? It's going to be too much effort to go back and modify all these too much. They all require different versions of loads of different libraries.

For instance in one markdown post I need to include JQuery, part of three.js and two other scripts.

I did work out how to get the inline scripts working (https://stackoverflow.com/a/50336890/170239) but would be nice to be able to load externally too.