# dangerouslySetInnerHtml still not rendeirng script

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am at wits end here. I just built out a website in React. But, the last piece of my website came from a third party. I was expecting some sort of api call but instead received a js tag that renders the element I need for their system. This script tag is a cdn type link that hooks up with the reservation system. I have tried to use dangerouslySetInnerHtml and a myriad of other plugins that claim to allow you to insert script tags into components. However, while the tag is present in the code (at least when I look in inspect mode) It is still not rendering anything. I have tried placing the same tag into the html and it works perfectly, so I know it is something to do with the component itself.

```
import React from 'react';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Row';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Col';
import Grid from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Grid';
import ScriptTag from 'react-script-tag';
import Safe from 'react-safe';

class ReservationForm extends React.Component{
  createMarkup = () => {
    return {__html: `<script LANGUAGE="Javascript" TYPE="text/javascript" SRC="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a7/React-icon.svg"></script>`}
  }
    render = () => {
      return (
        <Grid fluid>
          <Row className="reservation-form">
            <Col>
              <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.createMarkup()} />
            </Col>
          </Row>
          <Row className="icon-nav-bar">
              <Col col={3}>
              </Col>
              <Col col={3}>
              </Col>
              <Col col={3}>
              </Col>
              <Col col={3}>
              </Col>
            </Row>
        </Grid>
      );
    }
}

export default ReservationForm;
```

I unfortunately cannot include the actual cdn script here as it contains sensitive information. But, any help I can get would be much appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35614809/react-script-tag-not-working-when-inserted-using-dangerouslysetinnerhtml

Comment: I have tried following this tutorial a few times... However, the regex keeps returning 'null'... I think it is because what she is using here is between script tags... but what I need is the src inside of the script tag. Any suggestions?

Comment: @k-bice You just need to get the contents of your script src... (I'll recommend axios). And then use window.eval(contentsOftheScript).

Answer (score 0):

More than likely the underlying React code is using `innerHTML` or similar property / method which does not execute `<script>` elements when included.

You will have to manually create a script element and append it to the DOM through native methods like appendChild

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = "http://example.com/script.js";
document.head.appendChild(script)
```

Comment: So, I just tried this as well and I am still not getting the ui elements I need. But, I can see the script tag has been added to the head of the document. Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: @k.bice As long as you used the correct link to the javascript file it should be executed. Though without actually knowing what the code of that file is / does we can't be of much use. Is there any errors on the console? Is there anyway of providing the script without the sensitive information in it?

Comment: @k.bice If the script requires the `<Grid>` elements make sure you are rendering that content before including the script

Comment: I will try that... here is a sample of what the script looks like with the key taken out... <script type="text/javascript language="javascript" SRC="//openhotel.com/apps/hotel.cfm?key=keyforscript"></script>

Comment: looking at the code of the script it uses `document.write` and therefore it might be erroring out as it expects to be writing to a currently open document. Check the console for errors. It might be expecting to be included statically, ie not appended at some later time.

Comment: So this is the only related warning I have in the console: Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened.

Comment: I did try adding a async attribute to it... but it didn't seem to work I still go the same error.

Comment: I meant try adding it directly in your html like in your `<body>` tag instead of trying to add it dynamically. don't put async attribute on it just do it like you would any other script and see what it does. If it works(the script itself not the react part) like it supposed to you might need to reevaluate how you are trying to integrate that api, as it might not be compatible with a react type environment or might need to go back through their developer documents to see if there is something else you can use.

Comment: Okay I added it to the body and it did render... I noticed that when it rendered it brought in a few other script tags and a css link. Could this be the problem I am running into? Sorry, I looked for developer docs or a different way to apply the script tag.. but the company doesn't have one and I am desperate to figure this out.

Comment: In a nutshell, there is no way to add a script dynamically and execute it? That means if you want to load a big library in one page, you have to load it on the whole website? I found your post very interesting. I opened my issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62635153/how-to-make-a-script-working-the-first-time-for-a-special-component-with-gatsby/).