# How to make a script working the first time for a special component with gatsby?

Tags: gatsby, head, react-helmet

I am working on a static website project using Gatsby. I have several markdown pages, and only one is using a script through a cdn call. Instead of calling my script wherever i am on the website, I only to want to call and use my script when I need to update my `<head>`. That's why I started to use logical inside my Helmet component.

Actual version (calling on every pages):

```
return(
    <Layout>
    <Seo />
    <Helmet>
      <script src="myScriptForOnePage.js" />
    </Helmet>
    ....
    </Layout>
);
```

Excepted version:

```
return(
    <Layout>
    <Seo />
    { ifIHaveToRenderMyPage ? (
     <Helmet>
       <script src="myScriptForOnePage.js" />
     </Helmet>
    ):null}
    ....
    </Layout>
);
```

This works fine. My script is only loaded when I need it. **However**, It is not executed the first time when I load my special page... I need to go twice on my page to see my loaded script working.

This is an illustration of the issue. For example, in this [project](https://github.com/fabiendv/gatsbyBlog), I want to add a leaflet map. So, `myScriptForOnePage.js` equals to `https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js` (plus css file).

When I first load the page:

[image: going the first time to the post]

As you might see, `L is not defined`. My script is not executed even if it is present in the network statement. When I go back on the menu, and click again on leaflet post (without reloading):

[image: going the second time to the post]

The map is ready to be displayed.

Am I missing something in the life component? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Due to the asynchronously of Gatsby and your issue, you need to use an `state` to rerender the DOM and add a new component (`<Helmet>`) when your `ifIHaveToRenderMyPage` is set. Try:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';
const yourComponent = () => {
  const [myScript, setMyScript] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    let myScriptForOnePage= <Helmet>
      <script src="myScriptForOnePage.js" />
    </Helmet>;

    setMyScript(myScriptForOnePage);

  },[]);
return(
    <Layout>
    <Seo />
    {ifIHaveToRenderMyPage && myScript}
    ....
    </Layout>
);
```

So, basically I use a `useState` hook initially set as an empty array (must be an empty array to be filled with a component) and I've created an effect using `useEffect` hook that triggers when the component and DOM tree is generated (you can use `ifIHaveToRenderMyPage` as a dependency if you want by `[ifIHaveToRenderMyPage]`).

In addition, I've changed the ternary condition because you don't need to return a `null` value, just check if `ifIHaveToRenderMyPage`  is `true` using `&&` comparator, it's cleaner and efficient.

In my local machine with a `build` command and first rendering:

[image: Script loaded]

With the new updates, have you tried importing L from leaflet? As the [official documentation shows](https://react-leaflet.js.org/):

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Map, Marker, Popup, TileLayer } from 'react-leaflet'

const position = [51.505, -0.09]
const map = (
  <Map center={position} zoom={13}>
    <TileLayer
      url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
      attribution="&copy; <a href=&quot;http://osm.org/copyright&quot;>OpenStreetMap</a> contributors"
    />
    <Marker position={position}>
      <Popup>A pretty CSS3 popup.<br />Easily customizable.</Popup>
    </Marker>
  </Map>
)

render(map, document.getElementById('map-container'))
```

Comment: I have done what you suggested [here](https://github.com/fabiendv/gatsbyBlog).
If you go on the leaflet example post, it is not working for the first time. And if you go back to the main menu (without reloading) and click again on leaflet example, it is working

Comment: I udpated the question with screenshots. It might be useful

Comment: Have you checked the official Leaflet documentation for React? https://react-leaflet.js.org/

Comment: Yes I did. First, I cannot import component in markdown files. Then, I suppose that the problem doesn't come from leaflet because the script is working the second time. (Moreover, I tested with other scripts than leaflet, and I have the same issue :/)