# How to render script tag inside JSX without manually create it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I have HTML documents that I fetch from my backend. Those documents consist of 2 kinds of  tags and I want to render them dynamically. This is my source code

```
const Content = ({ slug }) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState()
  useScript("https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js");

  useEffect(() => {

    api.posts.read({ slug: slug }, { formats: ["html", "plaintext"] }).then((resp) => {
      setData(resp)
    })
  }, [slug])

  if (data) {
    return (
      <>
        <SEO
          title={data.title}
          description={data.meta_description}
          canonical_url={data.canonical_url}/>
          <section className={'content'}>
            <h4 className={'content-title'}>{data.title}</h4>
            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: data.html }}/>
          </section>
      </>
      )
  }
  return <Section>
    <CircularProgress style={{color: '#004D80'}}/>
    <p>Loading</p>
  </Section>
}
```

I tried these 2 but none of them works for my use case.

#### 1 `<script>` is rendered but not executed

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: data.html }}/>
```

#### 2

[React: Script tag not working when inserted using dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35614809/react-script-tag-not-working-when-inserted-using-dangerouslysetinnerhtml)

This is not working for my case. What if I have tags like
`<script src="https://gist.github.com/ogyalcin/66d0785998588ab50cf1908f8d43bb7b.js"></script>` in order to render a code block between two paragraphs? Besides, it is hard to handle if there are more attributes inside the tag.

Comment: well, it's purposefully set [not to be executed](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/72d00ab623502983ebd7ac0756cf2787df109811/packages/react-dom/src/client/ReactDOMComponent.js#L448)

Comment: Ya, is that any workarounds?

Comment: Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6432984/how-to-add-a-script-element-to-the-dom-and-execute-its-code

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, just a bit of feedback FYI. I did an experiment inside browser. Seems like the script tag is rendered. However the code inside isn't executed, not sure why.

```js
// @jsx

function App() {
  return <div><h1>React</h1><div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: window.thatScript }} /><h2>JS</h2></div>
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'></div>
<script>
window.thatScript = '<script type="text/javascript">function foo() {console.log("yolo")} setTimeout(() => foo()};<\script>'
</script>
```

Comment: This is because script tags injected via innerHTML are not executed for security reasons:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

Reference: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/8838

Answer (score 0):

May help:

Sample code from a create-react-app project.

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const danger = '<script>alert("Hello world!")</script>';

  useEffect(() => {
    const el = document.querySelector('.danger');
    el.appendChild(document.createRange().createContextualFragment(danger));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <h1>Render and execute script tag</h1>
      <div className='danger'></div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[image: Edit trusting-dream-i9ozk]

There may also be a library for that:

[dangerously-set-html-content](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dangerously-set-html-content)

> ```js
> import React from 'react'
> import InnerHTML from 'dangerously-set-html-content'
>
> function Example {
>
>   const html = `
>     <div>This wil be rendered</div>
>     <script>
>       alert('testing')
>     </script>
>   `
>
>   return (
>     <InnerHTML html={html} />
>   )
> }
> ```
>
> This will also work for scripts with the src attribute set it

Sharing good article for more information:
[Render dangerous content with React](https://dev.to/christo_pr/render-dangerous-content-with-react-2j7j)

> #### Render the danger
>
> Now what happens when you want to use dangerouslySetInnerHTML but also need to execute any script tag that comes inside the html? That's against HTML5 specifications, but if we dig a little bit more on what innerHTML do to inject the html we can found something interesting:
>
> The specified value is parsed as HTML or XML (based on the document type), resulting in a DocumentFragment object representing the new set of DOM nodes for the new elements.
>
> This DocumentFragment is a lightweight version of the document, it can have child nodes, the main difference is that since is a fragment, is not actually a part of the active/main document.
>
> We can create a DocumentFragment using the document.Range API.
>
> ```js
> import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
>
> // InnerHTML component
> function InnerHTML(props) {
>   const { html } = props
>   const divRef = useRef(null)
>
>   useEffect(() => {
>     const parsedHTML = document.createRange().createContextualFragment> (html)
>     divRef.current.appendChild(parsedHTML)
>   }, [])
>
>
>   return (
>     <div ref={divRef}></div>
>   )
> }
>
> // Usage
> function App() {
>   const html = `
>     <h1>Fragment</h1>
>   `
>
>   return (
>     <InnerHTML html={html} />
>   )
> }
> ```

[Reference on innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)