# Execute javascript code inside script-tag in React jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom, script-tag

I am adding this script-tag to my React jsx render:

```
<script>alert('Hello world')</script>
```

Why is the Javascript code `<script>alert('Hello world')</script>` not executing in my React app?

**Update:**

I am debugging this because I get this HTML back from api:

```
<div class="my-class" data-src="/event/66478667"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {var js,ijs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(d.getElementById(id))return;js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="https://embed.widget.js";ijs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ijs);}(document, 'script', 'my-js'));</script>
```

Now I am parsing this HTML through [html-react-parser](https://github.com/remarkablemark/html-react-parser) package like:

```
return <div data-testid="html-paragraph">{parser(html)}</div>;
```

But this isn't working because the Javascript code isn't executing?

How to solve this?

See here my [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/html-react-parser-v801ww?file=/src/Widget.tsx).

Comment: You should be using curlybraces { /* code here */} instead.
If you really want to use script tags, then you can use [reacthelmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet) to do that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React: Script tag not working when inserted using dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35614809/react-script-tag-not-working-when-inserted-using-dangerouslysetinnerhtml)

Comment: It is really not recommanded to do that. Because this will pop an alert Window each time the component is re-rendered. And depending on your whole applications, renders may happen very often!

Comment: What are you trying to do? What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: In your sandbox you are missing closing parentheses on `{alert('Hello world')}`

Answer (score 0):

You can add it via npm package. I used it as ( once ):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ScriptTag from 'react-script-tag';
 
class Demo extends Component {
 
    render() {
        return (<ScriptTag isHydrating={true} type="text/javascript" src="some_script.js" />);
    }
}
```

Here is the npm package link https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-script-tag

Answer (score -1):

Remove the `<script>` tag and replace with `{}`.

So: `{alert('Hello world')}`