# Is there a simple way to include a JSX file with script tag?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import

I am trying to include a bunch of React elements I have in file myfile.jsx
`<script type="text/babel" src="http://example.com/js/r/myfile.jsx"></script>`
This does not work.
If I try to put `import "http://example.com/js/r/myfile.jsx";` it tells me `require` is not defined.
Is there a simple way, via `script` tag to include jsx code?
I am using it on the web only, I use Babel to transpile it.
Below is my header, code works fine when all is in the same page.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34424845/adding-script-tag-to-react-jsx

Comment: I saw it ... so there is no straight forward way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to add `type='text/jsx'` in the script tag.
For example,

```
<script src="app.jsx" type="text/jsx"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to include type="text/babel", for example:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>

<!-- Load your-custom.js React file using type="text/babel" -->
<script type="text/babel" src="./js/your-custom.js"></script>
```