# Adding search box to React / JSX (using script tag)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, search-box

How can I add the following HTML to React/JSX in my render function?

```html
<a name="cjsearchboxanchor"></a>
<div class="cjsearchbox">
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.careerjet.de/partners/js_searchbox.html?n=7&nfr=1"></script>
    <div class="cjbotl bloggerDiv"></div>
</div>
```

What I have tried:

A) Using the following code, then just entering an ordinary (empty) 'script' tag in the JSX:

```js
  componentWillMount() { 
      const script = document.createElement("script")
      script.src = "http://www.careerjet.de/partners/js_jobbox.html   s=java&l=Schweiz&n=5&lid=38241&nfr=1&ntt=1";
      script.language = "javascript";
      script.type= "text/javascript";
      script.async = true;
      document.body.appendChild(script);
  }
```

- following [Adding script tag to React/JSX - Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34424845/adding-script-tag-to-react-jsx)

B) Appending 'embedCode' string containing the entire HTML from above to the JSX using jQuery with the following command: `$('.classNameOfMyDiv').append(embedCode);`
- following [Script tag in React - Codepad example](https://codepad.co/snippet/3rpBrhaz)

=> The search box does appear, but it is not possible to interact with it. This could be because of the following issue:

> "'Document': It isn't possible to
>       write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script
>       unless it is explicitly opened."

C) `npm install --save postscribe` - following [krux/postscribe](https://github.com/krux/postscribe)

D) Adding the HTML above to a `span` tag with `dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: ...}}`

Is there an easy way to fix this, or something else one can do to get this search box working with React? Any inputs would be greatly appreciated.