# React and Google Code for lead Conversion Page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, script-tag, react-redux-form

I have a simple react application with a contact form.

After submit I need to have this Google Code for lead Conversion Page showing on the page.

```
<!-- Google Code for Purchase Conversion Page -->
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    /* <![CDATA[ */
    var google_conversion_id = 1234567890;
    var google_conversion_language = "en_US";
    var google_conversion_format = "1";
    var google_conversion_color = "666666";
    var google_conversion_label = "xxx-XXx1xXXX123X1xX";
    var google_remarketing_only = "false"
        var google_conversion_value = 10.0;
        var google_conversion_currency = "USD"
    /* ]]> */ 
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" 
    src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/
    conversion.js">
    </script>
    <noscript>
    <img height=1 width=1 border=0 
    src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/
    conversion/1234567890/
    ?value=10.0&amp;currency_code=USD&amp;label=xxx-   
    XXx1xXXX123X1xX&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0">
           </noscript>
```

Since I can not add scripts into React - how can I do that?
I have been going around in circles trying to use HTML-loaders but nothing seemed to work (HTML-loader would have the script showing on the page).

Would really appreciate any help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess what you can do is one of these options:

1: Just add those scripts in your `index.html` file.

> If you are using webpack you need to have an index.html file, some [docs](https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/).

2: With a webpack plugin, add those scripts in a template. Then the plugin will do the job, more info [here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/output-management/).

```
// webpack.config.js
plugins: [
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: 'index.template.html'
  })
]
```

3: You can add a dynamic script tag: *response found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34424845/adding-script-tag-to-react-jsx)*

```
cbSuccess() {
  const script = document.createElement("script")

  script.src = "./your-script.js"
  script.async = true

  document.body.appendChild(script)
}
```

Comment: thank you for the quick response. The reason I can not use option 1 - it because I need those scripts on the page only after the form was submitted succesfully.  about option 2- I will read more in about the plugin and see if that can do the job. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I misunderstood your question :P, now I improved the response. Hope it can help you.

Comment: Thank you for the update! I will try the third option