# How integrate JS external resource in React project (Marketo)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, marketo

I'm actually going deeper in *React website* but I've found really tough integrate external library code.

I'm actually handling Marketo code (that generate a FORM) and it gets three elements:

- External file linked
- Div with id for the Form
- Script that write inside the DIV

```html
    <script src="//app-sjst.marketo.com/js/forms2/js/forms2.js"></script>
    <form id="mktoForm_1057"></form>
    <script>
      MktoForms2.loadForm("//app-sjst.marketo.com", "785-UHP-775", 1057, function(form){
        //Add an onSuccess handler
        form.onSuccess(function(values, followUpUrl){
          //get the form's jQuery element and hide it
          form.getFormElem().hide();
          //return false to prevent the submission handler from taking the lead to the follow up url.
          return false;
        });
      });
    </script>
```

How can I properly integrate in a class in React without using HTML?
I've written an idea but the url is not processed if injected with innerHTML.
Here's what I've done:

```js
import React
 from 'react';
import PropTypes
 from 'prop-types';

const scriptMarketo = <script dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: `
  MktoForms2.loadForm("//app-sjst.marketo.com", "785-UHP-775", 1057);
  console.log('test');
 ` }} />;

class MarketoForm extends React.Component {
 render() {
  return <div>
   <form id="mktoForm_1013"></form>
   {scriptMarketo}
  </div>;
 }
}


export default MarketoForm;
```

Many thanks in advice!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding script tag to React/JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34424845/adding-script-tag-to-react-jsx)

Comment: Alternatively you can make it pure react by building the form out and submitting - seems Marketo has a nice API - http://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/assets/forms/

Comment: you could use npm package made for marketo have a look here https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-marketo

Comment: instead of this you can import it in index.html

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you are still stuck. Ran into a similar issue thought it might be helpful. The link [Adding script tag to React/JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34424845/adding-script-tag-to-react-jsx) in the comments is close, just needed to adjust things a bit to deal with Marketo

```
  class MarketoForm extends Component {
  /**
   * need to inject
   */
  componentDidMount() {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    // Depending on your lint, you may need this
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
    MktoForms2.loadForm("//app-sjst.marketo.com", "785-UHP-775", 1057)
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <form id="mktoForm_1013"></form>
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
};
```

Some of this also depends on what type of state model you may be using. Not certain you want to re-render the Marketo form on a state update, so I am using `componentDidMount`