# React not showing feather icons

Tags: reactjs

Trying to include feather icons into react component but it is not showing up.

```
const SomeComponent = () => {
<div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/feather-icons/dist/feather.min.js"> </script>
    <script>
        feather.replace()
    </script>
    <i data-feather="home"></i>
</div>
}
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: [This might be interesting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34424845/adding-script-tag-to-react-jsx)

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the script in your index.html(so that it becomes globally available)

   ```
   <script src="https://unpkg.com/feather-icons/dist/feather.min.js"> </script>
   ```
2. Now go to your component and use the below code

   ```
   <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:window.feather.icons.home.toSvg()}} />
   ```

Comment: hmmm thanks for the answer.. any reason why the initial code doesn't work?

Comment: i believe script tag in JSX doesn't work (think its not part of dom tree, and it gets ignored). in your case am sure that the feather.min.js is not loaded