# how to add bootsrap link in specified reactJS file?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

i'm using react js for my project and i needed to use bootstrap in some pages of my application , so i put the     `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />`
in the Public folder in index.html 
but that apply the bootsrap in all pages ..fontFamily has been changed in pages ..

i want to apply it for a specific react js file

how can i import     `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />`
 in a react js file please ?

thanks for your help .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34424845/adding-script-tag-to-react-jsx Have you seen this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding script tag to React/JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34424845/adding-script-tag-to-react-jsx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install bootstrap npm package

```
npm install bootstrap
```

and then import it in JS files

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

The link below will help

[How to use Bootstrap with React](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-use-bootstrap-with-react-a354715d1121)