# Render script tag in React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm making a React application and I need to run a `Javascript` script only in one component, making reference to one of the `div`'s.

I know there are some libraries to do so, but I wonder if there's a more direct way to do it. Right now I do this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "../ThisComponent.css";

export default class MyComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div id="scriptTarget" />
        <div className="main">
          // Other stuff
        </div>
        <script src="js/myScript.js" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

But nothing happens. The script is stored in `public/js/myScript.js`.
Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding script tag to React/JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34424845/adding-script-tag-to-react-jsx)

Comment: Why wouldn't you *import* the script, and then call into it to trigger its behavior on the div from `componentDidMount`?

Comment: If he wants to add the script tag to that specific element the mentioned answer won't work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I finally solved it by adding the `componentDidMount` function before rendering the component. Like this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "../ThisComponent.css";

export default class MyComponent extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const script = document.createElement("script");

    script.src = "js/myScript.js";
    script.async = true;

    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div id="scriptTarget" />
        <div className="main">
          // Other stuff
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

If somebody has a better solution please feel free to share it. I'll be aware to further recomendations.

Answer (score 4):

By using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` you can add any valid html you want to your elements.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "../ThisComponent.css";

export default class MyComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML="<script src='js/myScript.js' />" >
        <div id="scriptTarget" />
        <div className="main">
          // Other stuff
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I should mention though that as the attribute name suggest, its use is **strongly discouraged**.

Answer (score 3):

```js
export default class MyComponent extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        const script = document.createElement("script");
        script.innerHTML = "window.onload = function() {\n" +
            ...
            "}"
        script.async = true;
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a external component "Helmet" for implement script tags and you can also use link tag,meta tag,style tag etc with the help of this component.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).