# How to embed custom script tag in functional component returning form Jsx in React.js and typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jsx

Variable **captchaContent** includes `<script src="something"/>` script tag that need to insert in form to render captcha for validation in further process.

I have provided only jsx part of the typescript file.

```
import { captchaContent } from '@dummy/security-token-validate-context';

export const Login = () => {
  return (
    <form name={'loginForm'} method="POST" onSubmit={onSubmit} className={classes.container} autoComplete="on">
      <Card className={classes.card}>
        <CardHeader className={classes.header} title="Login" />
        <CardActions>
          <Button
            variant="contained"
            size="large"
            type="submit"
            color="secondary"
            className={classes.loginBtn}
            disabled={state.isButtonDisabled}
          >
            Login
          </Button>
          {/*  TODO: Research how to embed captchaURl in form */}
        </CardActions>
      </Card>
    </form>
  );
};
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to render the `<script>` HTML tag as-is in your component? In that case, does this answer help? [Render script tag in React Component](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53805419/996081)

Comment: Hi @cbr, dangerouslySetInnerHTML is not a safe way to embed script. So, I am looking for a more efficient solution for this.

Comment: It's unsafe if you don't control the HTML you're rendering, e.g. if you render an user-input string. Your case sounds like the script comes from a safe, trusted source. If you're not satisfied with it, please expand more on what `captchaContent` is and where it comes from.