# Loading an array of <script> in Reactjs componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting to grips with React.js and trying to load some external scripts. I'm not just loading one script; there are multiple: at least three per page.

I want to load them dynamically rather than putting them in index.html, because I don't need them on every page.

I then want to fire `onload`, to prevent my function running until the scripts have been loaded.

I've tried creating an array and using `onload`, as in the example below. The scripts load in the `<head>` correctly, but the function doesn't.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    const scripts = [
        '/js/script1.js',
        '/js/script2.js',
        '/js/script3.js',
    ];
    scripts.forEach(s => {
      const script = document.createElement("script");
      script.type = 'text/javascript';
      script.src = s;
      script.async = true
      document.head.appendChild(script);
    })

    scripts.onload = function() {
      foo...
    }
  }
```

I've also tried using `Helmet` and `react-async-script-loader`, but neither worked because the scripts weren't loaded before the function, which meant that I got `undefined` errors.

I'd be grateful if anyone could explain how I can run the function only once the array of scripts has loaded.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding script tag to React/JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34424845/adding-script-tag-to-react-jsx)

Comment: may want to check out https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-async-script-loader since it'll do what you're after

Comment: One question to answer is: if you're using React for the entire site, then you wrote a web app, not really "a web page", so _why_ do you not want to just load those scripts as part of the React bundle? It's not like they get redownloaded for every page, your react app gets cached by the browser anyway?

Comment: Hi @Mike, thanks for your comment. There are 20 different pages with WebGL effects. Each uses different scripts and/or libraries (there is only one script in common across all of the pages). I don't want to load them all up front, because of the size of the js files and the fact that a user might not even visit every page for it to be worth caching them.

Comment: Hi @Juan, this isn't a duplicate. I'm trying to add an array of scripts in componentDidMount, not one script.

Comment: To at least make sure you're right about that: how big are we talking? Are your scripts huge, or just several kb each, which gzip will turn into "basically nothing"? React itself is _massive_ so unless your scripts add more bytes than a single image would (e.g. is it less than 200kb combined?) then frontloading it is effectively irrelevant. Remember to do the maths to prove to yourself that what you're thinking actually makes sense.