# How to execute <script> tag in react JSX without modify whole script content tag?

Tags: reactjs

Cant execute script tag inside react JSX.
I have a var with full script tag and code content and I cant modify it to create script as obect.

For example:

```
const html = <script type=\'text/javascript\'>console.log(1)</script>
```

So, I need execute html, ex:

```
render(){ return ( <div>{html}</div> )}
```

But it doesnt work, looks like code added after page render and DOM doesnt understand that script tag was append and execute it.

Comment: `render () { console.log(1); return ( <div></div> );}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding script tag to React/JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34424845/adding-script-tag-to-react-jsx)

Comment: Can we ask more about the specific use case for this, and why you might want to manually add a script tag in to your html using jsx

Comment: I cant modify variable with script tag. So, in html I have a string <script type=\'text/javascript\'>console.log(1)</script> and cant remove anything from that var

Answer (score -2):

Find **easy** solution with react-postscribe.

```
<PostScribe html={'<script type="text/javascript">console.log(1)</script>'} />
```