# Call a function defined inside script tags, from curly braces

Tags: html, reactjs

I tried importing a javascript library with a script tag, and then called a function from it inside React curly braces. I got an error telling me that the function wasn't defined.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/marked/marked.min.js"></script>
<p>{marked(string)}</p>
```

I know that I could import the library inside the react App file, or that I could use another script tag to call the function, but my question is: is there a way to call functions defined inside a script tag from React curly braces?? And viceversa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot include script tag inside your React component, instead you should include it in your HTML.

Once included, you should be able to use the functions as global functions (if the library is designed to be use as such)

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {marked("Function marked() is accessible as global function")}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<!-- 
Here you include your script in the HTML, then 
you can access the functions defined in the script
as global variable inside your React components
-->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/marked/marked.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: I'm building a single page react app that stores many mini apps, each of which is a component, so I wanted to import the library only for the mini app that needed it. Your answer doesn't really answer my question, but you helped me find a solution, which can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34424845/adding-script-tag-to-react-jsx

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear exactly what you're trying to do, but you can't import a library using the script tag. That's for html only. If you really want to do it that way, then you would have to do that script tag in the HTML file.

Or, the more standard approach, would be to install it using npm `npm install myLibrary`, then in the jsx file, you would do `import library from "myLibrary";

Let me know if you have any questions.