# Awaiting request, from non react source, inside a react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have used the calendly API inside my react component

I have tried with this code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import FullScreenModal from '../../../UIComponents/FullScreenModal'

export default class MeetingBooking extends Component {


    state={
        isLoading: false
    }
componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.state.isLoading)
    const head = document.querySelector('head');
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute('src',  'https://assets.calendly.com/assets/external/widget.js');
    head.appendChild(script);
    this.setState({loading: false})
}


    render() {
        console.log(this.state.isLoading)
        return (
            <FullScreenModal open={this.props.open} title={"Book a Meeting"} handleClose={this.props.handleClose}>
            {this.state.isLoading ?
            <p>Loading...!!!!</p> : 
            <div
             className="calendly-inline-widget" 
             data-url="https://calendly.com/kristofferlocktolboll"
             style={{minWidth: '320px', height: '580px'}}>
             </div> 
            }
             </FullScreenModal>

        )
    }
}
```

the issue is that I can't await the request from the URL the same way I could with an `Axios` or `fetch API` request, so whenever the script is inserted, the loading component is not even shown.

So I'm looking for some way to listen to the injected javascript, and await it, so I can show my `<p>Loading....!!!!</p>` in the meantime, can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `load` event listener to the `<script>` element, here is an example:

```
export default class MeetingBooking extends Component {

  state = {
    isLoading: false
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ isLoading: true }, () => {
      const script = document.createElement('script');
      script.type = 'text/javascript';

      script.onload = () => this.setState({ isLoading: false });

      script.src = 'https://assets.calendly.com/assets/external/widget.js';
      document.head.appendChild(script);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import FullScreenModal from '../../../UIComponents/FullScreenModal'

export default class MeetingBooking extends Component {


    state={
        isLoading: true
    }
async componentDidMount() {
   if (this.state.isLoading) {
    const head = document.querySelector('head');
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = 'https://assets.calendly.com/assets/external/widget.js';
    script.async = true;
    head.appendChild(script);
    await this.setState({loading: false})
  }
}


    render() {
        console.log(this.state.isLoading)
        return (
            <FullScreenModal open={this.props.open} title={"Book a Meeting"} handleClose={this.props.handleClose}>
            {this.state.isLoading ?
            <p>Loading...!!!!</p> : 
            <div
             className="calendly-inline-widget" 
             data-url="https://calendly.com/kristofferlocktolboll"
             style={{minWidth: '320px', height: '580px'}}>
             </div> 
            }
             </FullScreenModal>

        )
    }
}
```

Comment: i took an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34424845/adding-script-tag-to-react-jsx, hope, it helps you

Comment: it did not solve the problem unfortunately, cause, there is yet a way to listen to the script..

Comment: Dynamically created script elements are loaded async by default ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#Attributes)) and that doesn't mean that the code execution pauses until the script is loaded.