# How to inject Tradingview js into React Typescript render function?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, tradingview-api

I wanted to add some widgets in my Typescript React component. [Here is the embed code](https://in.tradingview.com/widget/ticker-tape/)

```
export default class App extends React.Component {

  render(): ReactNode {
    return (
      <div>
        Chart test
        <div className="tradingview-widget-container">
          <div className="tradingview-widget-container__widget"></div>

          <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-ticker-tape.js" async>
            {JSON.stringify({
              "symbols": [
                {
                  "proName": "OANDA:SPX500USD",
                  "title": "S&P 500"
                },
                {
                  "proName": "OANDA:NAS100USD",
                  "title": "Nasdaq 100"
                },
                {
                  "proName": "FX_IDC:EURUSD",
                  "title": "EUR/USD"
                },
                {
                  "proName": "BITSTAMP:BTCUSD",
                  "title": "BTC/USD"
                },
                {
                  "proName": "BITSTAMP:ETHUSD",
                  "title": "ETH/USD"
                }
              ],
              "colorTheme": "light",
              "isTransparent": false,
              "displayMode": "adaptive",
              "locale": "in"
            })}
          </script>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Seems like the same is rendered on the browser DOM as well. Unfortunately, the chart never gets loaded:

[image: the chart never gets loaded]

[Working perfectly in jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xameeramir/7uyfskgj/)

Note that the JSON data is also passed to the script. [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34424845/adding-script-tag-to-react-jsx) doesn't talk about it.

Seems like I'm doing it wrong. What is the right way to inject it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34424845/adding-script-tag-to-react-jsx

Comment: @Dupocas So fast! Impressive!!! I'll check and post here. Once confirmed probably we can close this as duplicate.

Comment: No problem. Not sure if is the same use case

Comment: @Dupocas No, I tried that solution. It doesn't work. If you might have noticed - we need to pass the data also. How can the data also be passed to the script URL?

Comment: This is the widget? https://www.tradingview.com/widget/ticker-tape/

Comment: I've managed to find a solution. I'll post an answer

Comment: @Dupocas Yup this is the widget!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me!

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount(): void {

      if (document.getElementById("chart")) {
        const script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = 'https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-ticker-tape.js'
        script.async = true;
        script.innerHTML = JSON.stringify({
          "symbols": [{
            "proName": "OANDA:SPX500USD",
            "title": "S&P 500"
          }, {
            "proName": "OANDA:NAS100USD",
            "title": "Nasdaq 100"
          }, {
            "proName": "FX_IDC:EURUSD",
            "title": "EUR/USD"
          }, {
            "proName": "BITSTAMP:BTCUSD",
            "title": "BTC/USD"
          }, {
            "proName": "BITSTAMP:ETHUSD",
            "title": "ETH/USD"
          }],
          "colorTheme": "light",
          "isTransparent": false,
          "displayMode": "adaptive",
          "locale": "in"
        });

        document.getElementById("chart")!.appendChild(script);;
      }

    }


    render(): ReactNode {
      return (<div id="chart"> </div>);
      }
    }
```