# TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of null

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, gatsby

I have been trying for a while to get this to work, to no success. I am trying to use material.iu inside of gatsby, but the javascript elements are giving me a null querySelector. I am new to React and Gatsby and I am not sure if it is a React problem or a Gatsby problem. [here is the error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gc4ua.jpg)

[image: Here is the is listener being called. Everything in {37-41} is the html for the material module.]

[image: This is the instantiation of MDCSelect (MDCSelect is called in Component.js[![][3]]][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AT7Xs.jpg)

Comment: Do you absolutely need to have a script tag inside your React Code? Maybe this question might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34424845/adding-script-tag-to-react-jsx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not going to work because you are essentially just adding a script tag in your JSX markup. If you absolutely must add a script tag to your gatsby site you can do it a couple of ways, either by looking at using the static folder or react-helmet. Check these two links, they should help you:

- [using the static folder in gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/static-folder/)
- [add script tag to header or body in gatsby project](https://uxworks.online/how-to-add-a-script-in-head-or-body-tag-in-your-gatsby-website/)

Comment: I see. But then how would I add in the drop down without using the script tag? I am just trying to create a drop down menu that sorts components in various ways.