# How to add async script to React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

I need to add a `div` & `async script` at the bottom of the page in my `react` application.

**1st Try:**

```
  ...
  ...
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <HeaderComponent />
        <Notifications />
        {children}
        <FooterComponent />
        <div
          className="cc-banner-embed"
          data-config="YmFja2MGVUJhY2tncm91bmQ9dHJ1ZQ==">
          <script async src="https://banner.crowdcube.com/embed.js"></script>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

**2nd Try:**

```
  ...

  // use lifecycle method to load script
  componentDidMount() {
    const s = document.createElement("script");
    s.type = "text/javascript";
    s.async = true;
    s.src = "https://banner.crowdcube.com/embed.js";
    this.instance.appendChild(s);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <HeaderComponent />
        <Notifications />
        {children}
        <FooterComponent />
        <div
          className="cc-banner-embed"
          data-config="YmFja2MGVUJhY2tncm91bmQ9dHJ1ZQ=="
          ref={el => (this.instance = el)}>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Unfortunately, both of these didn't work. How do I get this script file to load async.

EDIT:
My code was actually correct, however, in this case, the browser for some reason wasnt displaying it (cookie issue maybe). Going in incognito did the trick. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding script tag to React/JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34424845/adding-script-tag-to-react-jsx)

Comment: thanks Juan, I edited my question to say, my code was correct & the issue was related to cookie. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try this to load your script to your react app

```
  componentDidMount() {
    const head = document.querySelector('head');
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute('async',true);
    script.setAttribute('src', 'https://banner.crowdcube.com/embed.js');
    head.appendChild(script);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for looking into this, however, this didn't work. If it was in `head`, I could use React-helmet package.