# How do I use Embed Code in React with Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, embed

I have the following embed code I need to integrate into my React app (using hooks):

```
<script 
class="123abc" 
type="text/javascript" 
src="https://cdn2.fake.com/Scripts/embed-button.min.js" 
data-encoded="lsakjdfioejfklsdKLJFLDSidjfklJSDJfLFKJEI88DdfDF8Ad9sa7">
</script>
```

How would I go about doing this? The resources I've found don't seem to allow me to implement the data-encoded part...

Based on [Adding script tag to React/JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34424845/adding-script-tag-to-react-jsx/34425083#34425083) you can see the answer has a useEffect & hooks solution, but I can't figure out how I would implement the data-encoded part (or the class part for that matter).

Answer (score 1):

you can create a portal to add a script block instead of mutating the DOM directly from within your react script!

Comment: Okay. How do I.... create a portal? Never heard of that before.

Comment: :))) dont be angry dude, here is the link you rescue : https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html

Comment: Thanks man! Definitely not angry haha. I'll do some reading up, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For editing the documents head usually you use [`react-helmet`](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet).

> Supports all valid head tags: title, base, meta, link, script, noscript, and style tags.

Comment: Thanks Dennis, however it's not the document head that I want to modify. I want to insert a embed button from a finance partner into a component within my react app so that the button renders. Would `react-helmet` accomplish that?

Comment: You add the script to documents head, yes react-helmet does that - read the docs

Comment: I've read the docs (which are very confusing), but am not having any success. I'm using Next.js for SSR, so maybe that's the issue. But clearly just importing `import { Helmet } from "react-helmet";` then doing `<Helmet><script ....></script></Helmet>` doesn't work.

Comment: Next.js has it's own head management system, which is next/head, it's almost the same as react-helmet.

Comment: Okay, looking into that now! Thanks!

Comment: Consider just asking another question and upvoting answer which helped you.

Comment: Thanks Dennis, I've done so here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60919281/how-to-use-next-head-to-render-a-script

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
componentDidMount () {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "https://cdn2.fake.com/Scripts/embed-button.min.js";
    script.async = true;

    document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @jon-jones, but I'm using React Hooks (i.e., ComponentDidMount is not a thing). This is partially why I am stuck. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34424845/adding-script-tag-to-react-jsx/34425083#34425083 where they used the code you provided, and then later updated it to use hooks. However, in the hook example, I don't know how I would access the data-encoded...