# Access MathJax.Hub with MathJax loaded dynamically as script in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mathjax

I imported MathJax dynamically in React by adapting the accepted (updated) answer from [Adding script tag to React/JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34424845/adding-script-tag-to-react-jsx), that is:

```
const MathJaxScript =() => {
  const script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  script.src = 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js';
  script.async = true;

  var config = 'MathJax.Hub.Config({' +
                 'extensions: ["tex2jax.js","TeX/AMSmath.js","TeX/AMSsymbols.js"],' +
                 'jax: ["input/TeX","output/HTML-CSS"],' +
               'tex2jax: {inlineMath: [ ["$","$"], ["\\(","\\)"] ],displayMath: [ ["$$","$$""], ["\\[","\\]"] ],processEscapes: true}});'
               +
               'MathJax.Hub.Startup.onload();'
               ;
      document.body.appendChild(script);
    return () => {
      document.body.removeChild(script)
    }
};
export default MathJaxScript;
```

LaTex now displays nicely on my pages, but when I update the content, the new LaTex content is not parsed by MathJax. I would need to call `MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);` to do so. What is the best way to access `MathJax.Hub` using my current setup?

Comment: MathJax v3 has a completely different API. The config won't work and MathJax.Hub no longer exists. You might want to check the documentation starting at http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/advanced/typeset.html.

Comment: Thanks, I'm having a look at the doc. It also explains why the config was not working. Do you have any idea How I could load it properly? I need a MathJax= instead of MathJax.Hub.

Comment: The page [http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/web/typeset.html](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/web/typeset.html) is probably a better starting point, as it is more complete.

Comment: May I suggest you use a package for this? I can recommend [better-react-mathjax](https://www.npmjs.com/package/better-react-mathjax) that I wrote. Either you can use it altogether and don't care about typesetting details, or you can use it just to handle the download of MathJax and then access the `Hub` or `startup` properties (depending on which version you use) by means of the `MathJaxBaseContext` as shown [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/better-react-mathjax-custom-example-latex-e5kym)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Peter's comment, I was able to load MathJax just using this:

```
const MathJaxScript =() => {
  const script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  script.src = 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js';
  script.async = true;
};
export default MathJaxScript;
```

Then after calling the script,

```
window.MathJax={tex: {inlineMath: [["$", "$"], ["\\(", "\\)"]],packages: ["base", "newcommand", "configMacros"]},svg: {fontCache: "global"}};
```

To change the configuration.

I realized that this appears in fact the latest doc released:
https://docs.mathjax.org/_/downloads/en/v3.0-latest/pdf/