# Putting a script widget in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, widget

I'm trying to add a script tag in React,
`<script src='https://squareup.com/appointments/buyer/widget/40tyyrjazxhd8u/B4GN8P3Q0N0Y8.js'></script>`,
that contains a widget from an online booking site, how would I be able to add it in React?

Thank you !

Comment: This may already be answered. Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34424845/adding-script-tag-to-react-jsx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, something like this might work on your `componentDidMount()`:

```
 componentDidMount() {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "https://squareup.com/appointments/buyer/widget/40tyyrjazxhd8u/B4GN8P3Q0N0Y8.js";
    script.async = true;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
 }
```

Here's a [sandbox](https://cepc0.csb.app/)