# Append multiple script tags to head that execute synchronously in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, create-react-app, react-helmet

I'm trying to add multiple script tags to the head of a page in React using `react-helmet`. I want these scripts to execute in the order they're included, as one would normally expect in regular HTML. But it seems there is a [known bug](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet/issues/419) in `react-helmet` which makes the scripts load asynchronously and they get executed in a random order which messes up the intended use since some scripts are dependent on other ones.

Is there a way to append multiple script tags to the `<head>` of a page in react so they execute in order?

Here's my code:

```
    <Helmet>
      {isPermissionAllowed && (
        <script type="text/javascript" src={getFirstEndpoint()}></script>
      )}
      {isPermissionAllowed && (
        <script type="text/javascript">{`window.sample = "${getSample()}";`}</script>
      )}
      {isPermissionAllowed && (
        <script type="text/javascript" src={getSecondEndpoint()}></script>
      )}
      {isPermissionAllowed && (
        <script type="text/javascript">window.example.text["app.sample"] = "sample";</script>
      )}
    </Helmet>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this way inside your `app.jsx`:

```
const script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = 'Script source';
// script.[add attributes requires to you]
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

Comment: I came across a similar approach using hooks suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34425083/7435656). But this seems to work fine when the script is hosted somewhere for using the "src" attribute. What about a script tag that has code inline like `<script>console.log("something")</script>`?

Also, if we create a custom hook that uses the code you suggested for including one script, and then use that hook multiple times inside a `useEffect`, would that make sure the hooks are executed in order?

Comment: Instead of creating hooks you could create functions for appending script tag and call those functions inside `useEffect`

Comment: A comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46654077/7435656) suggests that we need to add removeChild to our code as well otherwise we'll create infinite number of script tags in our html.