# How to use materialize dropdown in react

Tags: reactjs, materialize

What I have is an app with react hooks where I just downloaded materialize as pure css.
Im trying to implement a button that will show a dropdown according to this:

```
https://materializecss.com/dropdown.html
```

Of course I don't have and don't want to have query. So the information there about how to trigger the dropdown are not usable.
Googling I realized that you should "import" M from materialize-css. Something like this:

```
import M from 'materialize-css';  

useEffect(){
    let elems = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-trigger');
    M.Dropdown.init(elems, {inDuration: 300, outDuration: 225});
}
```

But this will not work, of course. I do not have a component called "materialize-css". And I cannot import the very css file, which is not a component but a simple css file.
So what I did was to download from here:

```
https://materializecss.com/getting-started.html
```

And get the .js file. But what now? If i import this in my component like this:

```
    import M from 'materialize-css.js';
```

then everything gets broken. Just including that file from a component will make my app crash with a lot of errors about M.
Is this the way to go? Or how am I supposed to interact with materialize to change css on elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should install this package through npm `npm install materialize-css@next`

Then import it to your component `import * as M from 'materialize-css'`.Then it ready to go

If you prefer add js file instead of install package, you could read more here
[Adding script tag to React/JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34424845/adding-script-tag-to-react-jsx)