# React: adding embed script that has dynamic parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-helmet

I have a component which need to contain a `form` from `Marketo`.

In the backend, I have an ACF field called `form_id`. Idea being is that the user can input the Marketo form ID in the backend, and I will pass the value from that field into the `<script>` snippet in the component and it will find the relevant form.

Currently, I am trying to use `react-helmet`, however, it errors (`TypeError: tag[primaryAttributeKey].toLowerCase is not a function`) because of the field value from the backend.

Here is how the embed code appears from Marketo (with form ID 9999 used as an example):

```html
<script src="//url.com/js/forms2/js/forms2.min.js"></script>
<form id="mktoForm_9999"></form>
<script>MktoForms2.loadForm("//url.com", "999-XXX-999", 9999);</script>
```

And here is my current approach trying to get the value from backend to appear in place of `9999`:

```html
import React from "react";
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby";
import parse from "html-react-parser";
import {Helmet} from "react-helmet";

const ContactHero = (props) => {
  return {
  
  <div className="contactHero__form">
    <Helmet>
      <script src="//url.com/js/forms2/js/forms2.min.js"></script>
      <form id={`mktoForm_${parse(form_id)}`}></form>
      <script>MktoForms2.loadForm("url.com", "999-XXX-999", {parse(form_id)})</script>
    </Helmet>
  </div>
  
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is a special case, it looks like you can just call `MktoForms2.loadForm` in component such as:

```
useEffect(() => {
    MktoForms2.loadForm("url.com", "999-XXX-999", parse(form_id));
}, [form_id]);
```

The [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) will call its first parameter after the component has mounted, and the form is in the DOM. This way, the `MktoForms2.loadForm` function will be able to find the form. Without the `useEffect` the function will be called before the form is put onto the page by react and the function won't be able to find the form. The second parameter (`[form_id]`) to `useEffect` will call the function passed to `useEffect` whenever the `form_id` updates, or is initially passed to the component. You can import `MktoForms2` from whatever script file you are including in you html.

If you really must put the `MktoForms2.loadForm` inside a script tag, you should use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34424845/adding-script-tag-to-react-jsx), but it is easy to mess up react with script tags, especially if they edit the HTML document.