# Bootstrap JS not loading correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, frontend

So, I am trying to use Bootstrap in a React app. The Bootstrap CSS works properly, but anything that requires Bootstrap JS files doesn't work (dropdowns, modals, etc.) This is my code. I even tried copying the starter template and using that instead. It doesn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
  <meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app" />
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
  <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
  <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
  <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
  <title>React App</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>
  <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->


  <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- FontAwesome JS -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/8f8a8c35a9.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for all your help! :)))

Comment: Probably duplicated from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34425083/14032355).
Please have a look.

Comment: are you using [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/) package in your app? this could make the bootstrap use easier

Comment: @antoineso I didn't know there was a react-bootstrap package. I'll try it out, maybe it'll fix my issue.

Comment: @ikhvjs I'm not trying to put <script> tags inside a React component. I'm putting them inside the public/index.html which you get from creating a React app with CRA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using different versions of Bootstrap for CSS and JS

5.0: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/download/#cdn-via-jsdelivr

4.6: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/getting-started/download/#jsdelivr