# Embed a javascript game in a react application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have wrote a very basic video game in pure javascript (no framework).

This video game is composed of a .js file and a very basic html page which contains:

```
  <script src="js/mygame.js"></script>
  <script>
      $(function() { Game.run() });
  </script>
  <canvas id="game_zone"></canvas>
```

I want to embed this game in a script reactjs application.

I have tried to put a script tag in rendering return but the script is not loaded.

How should i do ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Could you try something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/34425083/198348, which creates it in a `useEffect()` block?

Comment: Thanks but in this case do you know if it is possible to fire an event from this js file which will be catched by react code ?

Comment: Not sure but would need to do some further investigation for it.