# How do I correctly add my LinkedIn Profile Badge to a React Application?

Tags: reactjs, linkedin-api

I am trying to add my LinkedIn Profile Badge to my portfolio I made using React using the instructions from LinkedIn. After adding the badge successfully the links on the badge are broken and causes the browser to stop displaying the badge.

LinkedIn gives you a script to use and a block of code depending on what size badge you want. I have listed those here and replaced my username with USERNAME_HERE.

```
<script src="https://platform.linkedin.com/badges/js/profile.js" async defer type="text/javascript"></script>
```

```
<div class="badge-base LI-profile-badge" data-locale="en_US" data-size="large" data-theme="light" data-type="HORIZONTAL" data-vanity="USERNAME_HERE" data-version="v1"><a class="badge-base__link LI-simple-link" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/USERNAME_HERE?trk=profile-badge">NAME_HERE</a></div>
```

I successfully got the badge to show up on my page using [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67675193/how-to-add-linkedin-profile-badge-to-react-app). However, the links that are displayed on the badge do not work as intended and cause the badge to crash until I reload the page. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loh81.png) is an image of the badge after clicking on one of the links.

What could be causing this issue?