# Execute Vanilla JS Scripts in React after DOM Render

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, web

I'm struggling my head for 5 hrs to get out of this issue, I've put some `<script>` tags in the `index.html` file that resides in the `public` folder.
I want them to execute after the Browser has rendered the HTML completely, I know this is very basic question, but the problem is, I'm converting an HTML template to React, and it heavily uses animations, which I can't afford to write in react again from start. Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Galaxy App</title>

    <!--CSS-->
    <link href="asset/css/icofont.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="asset/css/linearicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="asset/css/magnific-popup.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="asset/css/animsition.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="asset/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="asset/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="asset/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="asset/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="asset/css/homepage.css" rel="stylesheet" />


    <!--Theme CSS-->
    <link href="asset/css/theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="asset/css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.js"></script>

    <script src="asset/js/polyfill.min.js"></script>
    <script src="asset/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="asset/js/jquery.viewport.min.js"></script>
    <script src="asset/js/jQuerySimpleCounter.min.js"></script>
    <script src="asset/js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
    <script src="asset/js/animsition.min.js"></script>
    <script src="asset/js/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    <script src="asset/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="asset/js/rellax.min.js"></script>
    <script src="asset/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="asset/js/smoothscroll.js"></script>
    <script src="asset/js/svg4everybody.legacy.min.js"></script>
    <script src="asset/js/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
    <script src="asset/js/TimelineLite.min.js"></script>
    <script src="asset/js/typed.min.js"></script>
    <script src="asset/js/vivus.min.js"></script>
    <script src="asset/js/main.js"></script>
    <!-- Theme JS -->
    <script src="asset/js/theme.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.js"></script>
    <script src="asset/js/cutsom.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I manually checked by logging the `document.getElementById()` in the last script, and it returns undefined/null because at that time the HTML is not rendered completely, even though I've put the scripts at the end of file.
it works if I add `setTimeout` in my script, and it captures the elements perfectly.

So what should I do to only load all the scripts when my HTML has been rendered completely.

Comment: Somehow you have to know when React is done rendering. You can pass a callback function to `ReactDOM.render` and trigger any additional processing from there: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#render. This might require refactoring your existing code a little bit to make it callable on demand. Note however that changing DOM elements under React's control from the outside is usually a no-go.

Comment: I suppose you should use something like answers to this question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34424845/adding-script-tag-to-react-jsx

Answer (score 5):

One way to accomplish this is to emit an [Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) from React.

Add this to your main react component:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const event = new Event('rendered')
    document.dispatchEvent(event)
}, [])
```

Listen for the event on the page:

```html
<script>
    document.addEventListener('rendered', function() {
      // start animation
    }, false)
</script>
```