# Adding external javascript script to React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'd like to include & run some `js` file in the `React` using `Helmet` component. Here is the simple code:

*index.js:*

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  console.log("op");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Helmet>
        <script src="hello.js" type="text/jsx" />
      </Helmet>
      <h1>Hellok CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and ultra simple `js` script to include & run:

*hello.js:*

```
console.log("opl882...")
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

But the script seems NOT to work! - i have no console output and/or background color changed. What's odd when I use the `js` code as an inline code like:

```
 <Helmet>
   <script type="text/javascript">
     console.log("opl882..."); document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red"
   </script>
 </Helmet>
```

it works!

Why doesn't  the external `js` file work?

Comment: Do you have any errors? Is the file found? Try changing the script `type` attribute from `text/jsx` to `text/javascript`.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier When I change to `text/javascript` I'm getting an error: "Unexpected token '<'"...

Comment: try keeping the ```text/javascript``` and changing the source to src={"./hello.js"}

Comment: @BilalAbraham Unfortunately changing the source to src={"./hello.js"} DOEN'T helped - still getting  "Unexpected token '<'"...

Comment: @Daar44 I feel like you should just use my solution at this point

Comment: @BilalAbraham Have You any further idea why Helmet solution still doesn't work? It''s recommended on many sites/tutorials...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually do not implement .js files in react using a script tag. Instead you should import it at the top like this (assuming './hello.js' is the route to the file):

```
import './hello.js'
```

That file must also be located inside the src folder.

Comment: Ok, friend this method DOES work but I'm still curious why my doesn't?

Comment: @Daar44 I dont think ```<script></script>``` tags work at all in jsx u always have to import as modules. Also if you wanted to send a value from a .js file you would simply write ```export default VARIABLE_TO_EXPORT```

Comment: ok I'll accept and upvote but i/m still wondering why the solution with Helmet doesn't work!

Comment: @BilalAbraham [react-helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet#reference-guide) does support `<script>` tags.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Thank you lol, I didnt even realize you were using react helmet, why does emiels text/javascript not work... after all the type of the file should not be ```text/jsx``` because that .js file has no jsx

Comment: @BilalAbraham, I try several ways to add .js files to React, but didn't work out, unfortunately!  Then I try your way import .js files to the header, that works well, finally.  However, I run into another problem in some page: Getting null from some properties. This is because JavaScript loads before HTML code.  I am wondering if there is a way to import .js files which will be loaded after HTML code is completely loaded.  Please.

Answer (score 1):

I think the core issue you're probably seeing here is that `hello.js` is not accessible to the browser at the given URL. The `src` attribute in the `<script>` tag gives the URL for the browser to load the script from. Verify that you can directly access the script at the URL: it should just load as text in your browser to read if it's accessible.

The specifics of making a file directly accessible vary depending on your setup, but for a [standard Create-React-App project (and a lot of others) there is a folder called `public`](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/) and you can put files you need to directly access by URL in there. To verify it's working, add your file there, then try to access it from the root of your app. If your app is running at `localhost:3000` for instance, you can verify the file is accessible by navigating your browser to `localhost:3000/hello.js`. The file contents should appear in your browser as plain text. (Also, minor nitpick, I would use `/hello.js` as the `src` location, that feels like a less ambiguous URL to me.)

Once that's working, check out this StackOverflow over here to see about loading and running a vanilla JS file within React: [Adding script tag to React/JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34424845/adding-script-tag-to-react-jsx/34425083) .
In your case, you're already using Helmet, so I think the code you already posted is mostly good to work, but the answers in that link should help troubleshoot. Although I think you want to change the `type` to `text/javascript` or [just omit it entirely](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-type).

Finally, the reason the in-line JS works but not the referenced file is why I think it's about your browser not being able to find/access `hello.js`. The in-line JS just runs as it is because the JS is baked in. But to run it from a `src`, it has to find the source first, so if it can't find it at the URL you've given, it won't run. As for the other answer by Bilal here, that would work too, but it's depending on some sort of webpack magic or something to see it's a Javascript file, then pack it in such a way so that it runs. Nothing wrong with that necessarily, but you're basically offloading the creation of the `<script>` tag to whatever process interprets the `import`. (Also, note that if you're able to do `import './hello.js'`, then your `hello.js` file must live in your overall `src` folder, so it's not publicly accessible, which means the `script` `src` is invisible from the browser's POV.)

Answer (score 0):

```
useEffect(()=>{require('./paywell.js')},[])
```

Comment: It would be nice to give a brief explanation of how this works / how it solves the problem, and how it's different than existing answers.