# Is there a way to integrate the Google Cast SDK for Javascript into a React Web app?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

I am looking to use Google's cast SDK (for sending) in the Web app that I am working on; In google's documentation and codelabs ([https://developers.google.com/cast/codelabs#:~:text=Codelabs%20are%20sample%20apps%20with,Also%20see%20Sample%20applications.](https://developers.google.com/cast/codelabs#:%7E:text=Codelabs%20are%20sample%20apps%20with,Also%20see%20Sample%20applications.)) it seems that the only way to load the SDK is to use

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/cv/js/sender/v1/cast_sender.js?loadCastFramework=1"></script>
```

This won't work for me because I am writing a React+JSX web app. I can't just load the script through a script tag as the other elements that need to get rendered, such as the

```
<google-cast-launcher id="castbutton"></google-cast-launcher>
```

Aren't recognized as valid JSX elements.
How can I make this library available to my code? Is there anything like

```
yarn add cast-sdk
```

that exists that I can use to get the sdk?

Answer (score 0):

You can load the script directly on your `index.html` file. This way the script will load once together with your App.

Or you can dynamically load the script in the js like it is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34425083/19986141), but this way the script will be loaded/unloaded every time the component is mounted/unmounted.