# Adding inline <script src='...'> component using JSX in ReactJS

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx, render, src

I am trying to add two inline `script` components at a very specific position into my ReactJS application using JSX.

While in all three cases listed below, those `script` elements are added to the DOM tree at the desired position, there are no HTTP requests to the corresponding resources indicated by the scripts `src` attributes.

**Case 1**

```
return (
  <div
    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
      __html: `<script src='https://path.to/first/script.js'></script><script src='https://path.to/second/script.js'></script>`
    }}
  />
);
```

**Case 2**

```
return (
  <div>
    <script src='https://path.to/first/script.js'></script>
    <script src='https://path.to/second/script.js'></script>
  </div>
);
```

**Case 3**

```
import Safe from 'react-safe';
return (
  <div>
    <Safe.script src='https://path.to/first/script.js'></Safe.script>
    <Safe.script src='https://path.to/second/script.js'></Safe.script>
  </div>
);
```

So,

1: why these resources aren't loaded and executed like ... let's say an `<img src='...' />`  element?

2: how should we render inline `script` elements correctly?

Comment: The answer is in here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64815699/267887 (the why), and then I will second one of the opinions that you should use a script injector library written for react for this, as either way you will not want to deal with edge cases, figuring out if it loads, etc. yourself IMO. Bottom line you need to use a DOM API `body.appendChild(scriptElement)` to add dynamic script tags with JS like the days of old, to force the browser to recognize it and handle it correctly.

Comment: @Yuji'Tomita'Tomita you're right. Adding scripts with `node.appendChild(scriptEl)` method would leads to `Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened.` warning and fail. I'm still trying to find a package or another solution.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@charlietango/use-script use this!  the other part of the problem is reliably detecting if the script has loaded.