# How can I convert this html script tag code to react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom

I found a package but I am not sure because it´s not an official package, this is the html script tag code:

```
   <form>
        <script
            src="https://checkout.epa.co/checkout.js"
            class="epa-button"
            data-epayco-key="491d6a0b6e992cf924edd8d3d088aff1"
            data-epayco-amount="50000"
            data-epayco-name="Vestido Mujer Primavera"
            data-epayco-description="Vestido Mujer Primavera"
            data-epayco-currency="cop"
            data-epayco-country="co"
            data-epayco-test="true"
            data-epayco-external="false"
            data-epayco-response="https://ejemplo.com/respuesta.html"
            data-epayco-confirmation="https://ejemplo.com/confirmacion"
            data-epayco-methodconfirmation="get">
        </script>
     </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't convert an html website to a react project

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34424845/adding-script-tag-to-react-jsx)

Or you can also add your script tag to your index.html file in your react project. Typically it's under public folder.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).