# How to add an external js script in react.js

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to add the following script

```
<script src="//ad.lomadee.com/banners/script.js?sourceId=37645311&dimension=27&height=90&width=970&method=0" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
```

As this is an advertising script, I need to include it in several places in my app. For that reason, I'm not putting it in the HTML.

I would like to create a react component that can be called multiple times in different places.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding script tag to React/JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34424845/adding-script-tag-to-react-jsx)

Comment: why not just add it to your html master template?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans seems like this is an ad script that replaces itself with the actual ad

Comment: That's something Alexandre gets to explain, but in the absence of an explanation I'd assume this injects a new DOM note, not replaces the script node (which would be rather strange, given that script nodes typically live in the document head element)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 approach to include external scripts in react.js app.

1. Using react-script-tag Package
2. Using react-helmet Package

Please look at the following blog.

[https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-include-an-external-javascript-library-to-reactjs/#:~:text=Installation%3A%20Open%20a%20terminal%20inside,react%2Dscript%2Dtag%20Package.&text=Import%20'ScriptTag'%20component%3A%20Import,to%20add%20the%20script%20tag](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-include-an-external-javascript-library-to-reactjs/#:%7E:text=Installation%3A%20Open%20a%20terminal%20inside,react%2Dscript%2Dtag%20Package.&text=Import%20%27ScriptTag%27%20component%3A%20Import,to%20add%20the%20script%20tag).

Comment: I've tried usingo both, but for some reason didn't work.

Comment: Are you still having problem? contact me I can solve the problem. alektyler14@hotmail.com