# include javascript code that contains curly bracket in jsx

Tags: reactjs, next.js, jsx

```
    return <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
        <IntlProvider locale={locale} messages={messages} textComponent={Fragment}>
            <GoogleOAuthProvider clientId={GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID}>
                <div
                    onDragOver={handleDragOver}
                    onDrop={handleDrop}
                    onMouseOver={mouseOver}
                >
                    <Head>
                        <link rel='shortcut icon' href={favicon} type='image/png' />
                    </Head>
                    <div>
                        <div className={styles.page} onClick={handleCloseSupportChat}>
                            <div className={styles.pageContent}>
                                <Component {...pageProps} />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <script>
                        window.__lc = window.__lc || {};
                        window.__lc.license = 14728555;
                        ;(function(n,t,c){function i(n){return e._h?e._h.apply(null,n):e._q.push(n)}var e={_q:[],_h:null,_v:"2.0",on:function(){i(["on",c.call(arguments)])},once:function(){i(["once",c.call(arguments)])},off:function(){i(["off",c.call(arguments)])},get:function(){if(!e._h)throw new Error("[LiveChatWidget] You can't use getters before load.");return i(["get",c.call(arguments)])},call:function(){i(["call",c.call(arguments)])},init:function(){var n=t.createElement("script");n.async=!0,n.type="text/javascript",n.src="https://cdn.livechatinc.com/tracking.js",t.head.appendChild(n)}};!n.__lc.asyncInit&&e.init(),n.LiveChatWidget=n.LiveChatWidget||e}(window,document,[].slice))
                    </script>
                    <noscript><a href="https://www.livechat.com/chat-with/14728555/" rel="nofollow">Chat with us</a>, powered by <a href="https://www.livechat.com/?welcome" rel="noopener nofollow" target="_blank">LiveChat</a></noscript>
                </div>
            </GoogleOAuthProvider>
        </IntlProvider>
    </Elements>;
};
```

Above is jsx code, within the code

```
               <script>
                    window.__lc = window.__lc || {};
                    window.__lc.license = 14728555;
                    ;(function(n,t,c){function i(n){return e._h?e._h.apply(null,n):e._q.push(n)}var e={_q:[],_h:null,_v:"2.0",on:function(){i(["on",c.call(arguments)])},once:function(){i(["once",c.call(arguments)])},off:function(){i(["off",c.call(arguments)])},get:function(){if(!e._h)throw new Error("[LiveChatWidget] You can't use getters before load.");return i(["get",c.call(arguments)])},call:function(){i(["call",c.call(arguments)])},init:function(){var n=t.createElement("script");n.async=!0,n.type="text/javascript",n.src="https://cdn.livechatinc.com/tracking.js",t.head.appendChild(n)}};!n.__lc.asyncInit&&e.init(),n.LiveChatWidget=n.LiveChatWidget||e}(window,document,[].slice))
                </script>
                <noscript><a href="https://www.livechat.com/chat-with/14728555/" rel="nofollow">Chat with us</a>, powered by <a href="https://www.livechat.com/?welcome" rel="noopener nofollow" target="_blank">LiveChat</a></noscript>
```

Belongs to https://www.livechat.com/ that require to include for their chatbot; their setup guide: https://www.livechat.com/help/setting-up-livechat-on-your-website/?utm_source=webapp

But I  have the following error:

```
Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected "}"

  288 |                         window.__lc = window.__lc || {};
  289 |                         window.__lc.license = 14728555;
> 290 |                         ;(function(n,t,c){function i(n){return e._h?e._h.apply(null,n):e._q.push(n)}var e={_q:[],_h:null,_v:"2.0",on:function(){i(["on",c.call(arguments)])},once:function(){i(["once",c.call(arguments)])},off:fun
ction(){i(["off",c.call(arguments)])},get:function(){if(!e._h)throw new Error("[LiveChatWidget] You can't use getters before load.");return i(["get",c.call(arguments)])},call:function(){i(["call",c.call(arguments)])},init:function(){va
r n=t.createElement("script");n.async=!0,n.type="text/javascript",n.src="https://cdn.livechatinc.com/tracking.js",t.head.appendChild(n)}};!n.__lc.asyncInit&&e.init(),n.LiveChatWidget=n.LiveChatWidget||e}(window,document,[].slice))     
      |                                                                                                     ^
  291 |                     </script>
  292 |                     <noscript><a href="https://www.livechat.com/chat-with/14728555/" rel="nofollow">Chat with us</a>, powered by <a href="https://www.livechat.com/?welcome" rel="noopener nofollow" target="_blank">LiveChat</a></
noscript>
  293 |                 </div>
```

How should I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

the code inside of script tag is nothing but normal js,
script tag is used when it's a html file and you want to include some js in it.
as you are already using js, you can create a function containing the logic inside of the script tag and call it when needed from your code , the case might be when the component mounts.

Or,
you can add a iframe and include the script tag there,
you can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34424845/adding-script-tag-to-react-jsx/70971249#70971249:%7E:text=%3Ciframe%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20id,html%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%60%7D%0A%20/%3E) example.