# How to add javascript <script> tag code to React page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, drift

I have the following code below which is generated from Drift for a live chat widget.

```
<!-- Start of Async Drift Code -->
<script>
"use strict";

!function() {
  var t = window.driftt = window.drift = window.driftt || [];
  if (!t.init) {
    if (t.invoked) return void (window.console && console.error && console.error("Drift snippet included twice."));
    t.invoked = !0, t.methods = [ "identify", "config", "track", "reset", "debug", "show", "ping", "page", "hide", "off", "on" ], 
    t.factory = function(e) {
      return function() {
        var n = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        return n.unshift(e), t.push(n), t;
      };
    }, t.methods.forEach(function(e) {
      t[e] = t.factory(e);
    }), t.load = function(t) {
      var e = 3e5, n = Math.ceil(new Date() / e) * e, o = document.createElement("script");
      o.type = "text/javascript", o.async = !0, o.crossorigin = "anonymous", o.src = "https://js.driftt.com/include/" + n + "/" + t + ".js";
      var i = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
      i.parentNode.insertBefore(o, i);
    };
  }
}();
drift.SNIPPET_VERSION = '0.3.1';
drift.load('...');
</script>
<!-- End of Async Drift Code -->
```

And I am trying to add this code into a jsx file.

I have tried to include the above directly into what is returned in the jsx file, but that doesn't work.

I have also tried to put the above code into its own function and call it in what should be displayed on the screen using `{{}}` but that also didn't work.

The code doesn't have any errors, it only reports this in the console which tells me it's just being called.
`DRIFT_WIDGET:: widget_core:bootstrap_api finished in 201.60000002384186 ms`

Can someone please help in how I can add this widget to my page.

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding script tag to React/JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34424845/adding-script-tag-to-react-jsx)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this package.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-helmet

```
import React from "react";
import {Helmet} from "react-helmet";
 
class Application extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
        <div className="application">
            <Helmet>
             <!-- your script tag here -->
            </Helmet>
        </div>
    );
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks @hddananjaya I tried this and get unexpected tokens, it looks like the .js file doesn't like the formatting of that script and complains with 'var' variables and returning void, I'm not sure if react is interfering with this somehow.

Comment: @Joshua Hm. Did you try adding this to index.html?

Comment: Hey ! I added this but looks like it needs to be verified by Drift and added to the live domain instead of locally. Thanks a lot hddananjaya

Answer (score 0):

You can create a component that renders the script tag and then use it in your jsx file.

Example:

```js
import React from 'react';

const DriftScript = () => (
  <script>
    "use strict";

    !function() {
      var t = window.driftt = window.drift = window.driftt || [];
      if (!t.init) {
        if (t.invoked) return void (window.console && console.error && console.error("Drift snippet included twice."));
        t.invoked = !0, t.methods = [ "identify", "config", "track", "reset", "debug", "show", "ping", "page", "hide", "off", "on" ], 
        t.factory = function(e) {
          return function() {
            var n = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
            return n.unshift(e), t.push(n), t;
          };
        }, t.methods.forEach(function(e) {
          t[e] = t.factory(e);
        }), t.load = function(t) {
          var e = 3e5, n = Math.ceil(new Date() / e) * e, o = document.createElement("script");
          o.type = "text/javascript", o.async = !0, o.crossorigin = "anonymous", o.src = "https://js.driftt.com/include/" + n + "/" + t + ".js";
          var i = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
          i.parentNode.insertBefore(o, i);
        };
      }
    }();
    drift.SNIPPET_VERSION = '0.3.1';
    drift.load('...');
  </script>
);

export default DriftScript;
```

Then in your jsx file:

```js
import React from 'react';
import DriftScript from './DriftScript';

const MyComponent = () => (
  <div>
    <DriftScript />
  </div>
);

export default MyComponent;
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hey @Nuro007 thanks for the suggestion. I tried both suggestions from you and the one above, but I am getting issues with the syntax, I spoke about this in my comment in the suggestion above by hddananjaya, my error happens with suggestion and the above for some reason, maybe React somehow doesn't like the syntax.