# How can i access a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, undefined

So, for example, I have this `index.js` react file:

```
import React from "react";
import Helmet from "react-helmet";
import MyScript from "../javascript/myscript";

function Index(){
   return(
      <div id="index">
          <Helmet> 
              <script type="text/javascript" src="https://example.com/functions.js"/>
          </Helmet>
          <h1>Hello, test</h1>

          {MyScript()}
      </div>
   );
}

export default Index;
```

Then, the `https://example.com/functions.js` looks like this:

```
function Salute(){
   return console.log("Hello, world!");
}

function SayGoodBye(){
  return console.log("Good bye, world!")
}
```

And `MyScript` looks like this:

```
   Salute();
```

or:

```
   SayGoodBye();
```

I tried calling the function `Salute` from `MyScript`, but I get an error saying `Salute is not defined`.
How can I call the `Salute` function from `MyScript`?

Comment: You shouldn't be calling it like that, you can return a JSX from Salute function and not a console log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to export them first

```
export function Salute(){
   return console.log("Hello, world!");
}

export function SayGoodBye(){
  return console.log("Good bye, world!")
}
```

and then you can import them as

```
import {Salute, SayGoodBye} from "../javascript/myscript";
```

Comment: yeah, but how do i import them if the functions are in "https://example.com/functions.js"?
i can't do import{Salute, SayGoodBye} from "https://example.com/functions.js"

Comment: Refer this question for adding script in react - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34424845/adding-script-tag-to-react-jsx