# Why are <script> tags inserted via dangerouslySetInnerHTML not executed?

Tags: reactjs

I've got the following code that when first renders, an alert does indeed fire saying "hi".  However, when I click the "click me" button, and update the div to include the `alertString`, the alert does not fire.

What am I not understanding? I thought that the alert would fire when I click the button, not just render.

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function Page() {
  const alertString = "<script>alert('hi')</script>";
  const [val, setVal] = useState("default value");

  return (
    <>
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: alertString ?? "" }}></div>
      <hr/>
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: val ?? "" }}></div>
      <button onClick={() => {setVal(alertString)}}>Click me</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

EDIT:
Example with input:

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function Page() {
  const [alertString, setAlertString] = useState(`Enter an alert here...`);

  return (
    <>
      <input value={alertString} onChange={(e) => {setAlertString(e.target.value)}} />
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: alertString ?? "" }}></div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Type `<img src="https://www.siliconvalley-codecamp.com/Images/silicon-valley-code-camp.png" />` into input field and it renders.

Comment: I'm really trying to make sure I completely understand injection attacks. My example could have been better. That is why I want it to be a string like a user would type in. Assigning alertString a function defeats my intent.

Comment: Ahhh I see. Well react blocks that from happening as a security measure [please see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64815699/13428061). In order to test your injection  attacks/theories, you would have to add your own script tag.

Comment: What's odd is it does not block an img tag. for example, if I type <img src="https://www.siliconvalley-codecamp.com/Images/silicon-valley-code-camp.png" /> into an input field, the image renders. I'd think that would be a violation also

Comment: I added an example of just an input tag for inserting <img...

Comment: Input fields are not secure by default. Ideally developers add validation rules to their `input` fields to secure it.

Comment: Through the links posted here, I found this in the HTML5 spec https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html#innerhtml0. "script elements inserted using innerHTML do not execute when they are inserted."

Answer (score 0):

Through the links posted here, I found this in the HTML5 spec https://w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html#innerhtml0. "script elements inserted using innerHTML do not execute when they are inserted."