# Placing an iframe in root file (pugjs file) in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, iframe, pug

I am trying to use an iframe code within my react component. Obviously, this works:

```
export default function Newsletter({ page }) {
  return (
    <div className={`${styles.newsletter} newsletter-form`}>
      <div className={styles.newsletter__row}>
        <iframe
          src="https://blablabla.com"
          width="800"
          height="800"
          frameborder="0"
          title="Your iframe title"
        ></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

However, I need to also make use of these two tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var zmailApp ="ODA0MTc4NTAxMg";
    var lang ="df";
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=https://www.scripts.net/scripts/newAppV2.js></script>
```

And that does not play well within a react component. I even installed `react-helmets` to try to set these in the header. It's looking like I really do need to either have this React Component injected into the root file or find a way to apply those script tags by grabbing the react component from the pugjs root file itself. Any input is appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding script tag to React/JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34424845/adding-script-tag-to-react-jsx)

Comment: Your question seems to not be about putting an iframe in a React component, but rather putting script tags in a React component. If this is the case, updating the title of your question might get more engagement.