# I want to know how to do ssr with react

Tags: reactjs, node.js, typescript, server-side-rendering

I worked using Node's express to do SSR with React.

But the following error occurred.

^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
This error appears.

I asked chatGpt and they said it was because I used ESmodule, so I added "type": "module" to package.json to change Node's CommonJs to ESmodule.

The entire node code is shown below.

````
import path from "path";
import ReactDOMServer from "react-dom/server";
import App from "../src/App";
import { HelmetProvider } from "react-helmet-async";
import { StaticRouter } from "react-router-dom/server";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "redux/store";
import { StaticProvider } from "./contexts";

const app = express();

// 말그래도 노드의 서버 주소입니다.
// 나중에 ec2로 작업해서 주소를 환경변수에 넣어봅시다.
const port = process.env.PORT || 3001
// 정적 파일들을 제공하기 위해 express.static 미들웨어를 사용합니다.
// 정적 파일은 build 디렉토리에 있습니다.
// express.static는 Express 앱이 클라이언트에게 정적 파일들을 쉽게 제공할 수 있도록 도와줍니다. 
// 이 미들웨어를 사용하면 파일을 읽어오는 I/O 작업이 자동으로 처리되어 성능상 이점이 있습니다.
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "build")));


app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  // 라우팅된 경로 정보를 저장합니다.
  const context = {};
  // 메타데이터에 대한 정보를 수집합니다.
  const helmetContext = {};

    const appHtml = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <HelmetProvider context={helmetContext}>
          <StaticRouter location={req.url}>
            <StaticProvider value={context}>
              <App />
            </StaticProvider>
          </StaticRouter>
        </HelmetProvider>
      </Provider>
    );
  const { Helmet } = helmetContext;
  const html = `
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="ko">
      <head>
        ${Helmet.title.toString()}
        ${Helmet.meta.toString()}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css">
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="root">${appHtml}</div>
        <script src="/bundle.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
  `;

  res.status(200).send(html);
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is listening on port ${port}`);
}); ```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5S0Js.png
````

Comment: Please provide details as to where in your code that error is being thrown.  Is this error being seen on the server or in the browser? Maybe provide the entire stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

you can use iframe [like this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70971249) , as i searched the script tag can't be used as SSR on ReactJS