# How to display a script into a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to display a widget form from a reservation booking site into my application. I found how to load a script in my React Component and managed to make it work on the site. The only problem is that it doesn't show on the page unless i reload the page from the route of the page and when i start to visit the site from the root and go to the page, it doesn't load either.

I use useRef to target the div on my component and apply to it the appendChild method.
here is how i put the script on my component:

```js
function Tour({visitInfos}) {
    const scriptContainer = useRef(null);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        const baliseScript = document.createElement("script");
        baliseScript.src = "https://my_site_here.io";
        baliseScript.async = true;
        scriptContainer.current.appendChild(baliseScript);
    }, []);
}
```

```
                <div className="bookingSiteScript" ref={scriptContainer}></div>
           </main>
        
        </>
    )
}
```

I don't have any errors on my log when i load the page. I know that you are not supposed to alter the DOM directly when you are using React, so i am open for alternative.

Comment: You've problably gotten that approach from this link. So try the second answer about react-helmet: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34424845/adding-script-tag-to-react-jsx