HTML script tag isn't recognizing Javascript in React project
I'm trying to set up Swiper in my React project so I can have an image carousel, but the script I need to use isn't recognized, like it's not even recognizing the keywords 'const' or 'new' (as you can see they're just white).
code screenshot
Also, I get a simple "'}' expected" error on all the colons. Am I putting this code in the wrong place? Does React not support the script tag?
I currently have the script tag inside a <main> tag. I tried putting them in a <body> tag but this didn't work either.
Here is the code:
import 'swiper/css';
import 'swiper/css/navigation';
import Swiper from 'swiper';

export const Page = () => {
    return (
        <div className="Container">
            <main className="MainContent">
                <div className="swiper">
                    <div className="swiper-wrapper">
                        <div className="swiper-slide"><img className="SlideImg" src={a}/></div>
                        <div className="swiper-slide"><img className="SlideImg" src={b}/></div>
                        <div className="swiper-slide"><img className="SlideImg" src={c}/></div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="swiper-pagination"></div>
                    <div className="swiper-button-prev"></div>
                    <div className="swiper-button-next"></div>
                </div>
                    <script type="application/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@11/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
                    <script type="application/javascript">
                        const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
                            loop: true,
                            pagination: {el: '.swiper-pagination'},
                            navigation: {nextEl: '.swiper-button-next', prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev'}
                        });
                    </script>
            </main>
        </div>
    )
}


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

that's an editor issue it seems, the code in the pretty picture looks syntactically correct

Where is the rest of your code? Please provide a minimal reproducible example of the problem. Also, why are you adding type="application/javascript" to your <script> tag?

@kmoser I added the code. Sorry about that, this is my first StackOverflow post. Also there's no particular reason for the type="application/javascript", it was just something I was trying to see if it would work.

@JaromandaX I thought the same, but I put it into CodeSandbox as well and it still wasn't being recognized.

well, the code now is not like picture ... context

@JaromandaX I'm not sure what you mean. Do you mean the code I added doesn't have the errors that are in the screenshot? If so I don't think Stack Overflow is checking for syntax. Or do you mean something else?

The top answer (offsite link)   from a google search for "can you use script tags in a React component" basically says you can't inject a script into React DOM from JSX. Similar questions have been asked on SO and other forums in the past. Not being a Reactjs user I leave it to others to assess if there are existing questions on SO that are up to date and comprehensibly  answered .

Probably duplicated, check this question.

@Vashon - I'm saying, in the picture it's not apparent that you are using script tags inside JSX like that

You can check  this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34424845/adding-script-tag-to-react-jsx

But you can't <script> tags within your JSX to initialize JavaScript libraries in react project instead, you should initialize and configure these libraries within your React component using hooks like useEffect
You can check out these resources:
freecodecamp
swipper.js
React JS - React Tutorial for Beginners
